# Convert Array of Strings to Comma Separated String with additional concatenation

Tags: c#, string, linq, concatenation, delimiter

Is there any way to convert a list of strings to a comma-separated string?

```
String[] data = new String[] { "test", "abc", "123" }
```

Convert into:

```
'test', 'abc', '123'
```

Possible solutions:

1. Surround every string with `''` and then use `String.join` on the list.
2. `Foreach` each string in the list and do the concatenation of `''` and `','` and in the end remove last `','`

Is there any simple Linq (one line expression) to do both?

Comment: Use `var x = string.Join(", ", yourArray);`

Comment: @slugster, I hope I mentioned it in my approaches

Comment: Side note: make sure you are not trying to build JSON... may endup with square reinvented wheel.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is there any simple Linq (one line expression) to do both.

```
string.Join(",", data.Select(item => "'" + item + "'"))
```

Basics of Linq: Transforms are `Select` statements. Filters are `Where` statements.

That said, there are a lot of string manipulation tools available that aren't Linq, and they're more likely to be optimized for strings, so I'd always look to them before looking to Linq.

Comment: I linked to another question that is now deleted - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33471600/232593 - I think their code probably has better performance than mine, even though it doesn't use Linq. `return "'" + string.Join("','", data) + "'";`

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin - if you want to undelete your answer, I know I'd personally upvote it, even though there isn't any Linq to be found.

Comment: I also think Using linq everywhere is not good. When you look at the linq methods from inside you will see that you make a mess inside your program just to do a simple count!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary There is something to be said for readability and premature optimization, but I agree with you that being able to understand and make these tradeoffs is good. I call them out because I like people to be aware there is a tradeoff to make.

Comment: I was going to upvote AsadSaeeduddin's answer when he deleted it. I think his answer is good because of the simplicity. Maybe he deleted it because OP wants a solution using LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregate linq

```
Array.Skip(1).Aggregate(Array[0],(a,b) => string.Format("{0},'{1}'",a,b));
```

Comment: While smart looking, don't ever use that for real code with more than couple items due to O(n^2) performance...

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] data = new String[]{"test","abc","123"};
var result = string.Join(",", data.Select(o => string.Concat("'",o,"'"));
```

Comment: Style preference - why would you use `Concat` over `+` which generates identical code?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov for me, it's more easy to read `,`-separated arguments, ecpecially when it contains other operation like `+` and `condition ? true : false`. for example compare `"a" + ((a>1) ? "yes: " + variable : "no one") + "b"` and `string.Concat("a", (a>1) ? "yes: " + variable : "no", "b")`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Aggregate method:
Example:

```
List<string> fruit = new List<string> {"Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Tomato", "Banana"};
var fruitSentence = fruit.Aggregate((current, next) => $"{current},{next}");
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: if you're starting with IEnumerable or similar you have to call .ToArray() at the end of the LINQ statement like this:

```
input parameter: IEnumerable<string> feederIdList    

var feederListString = String.Join(",", feederIdList.Select(feeder => "\"" + feeder + "\"").ToArray());
```

In my case I needed each string to have double quotes around it for passing into an Oracle stored procedure later.